# How to pass a function with arguments via JavaScript object array?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a list of items, and I want to feed its data from a JavaScript array:

```
// HTML
<ul
  <li v-for="menuItem in menuItems">
    <a @click="menuItem.action">{{ menuItem.name }}</a>
  </li>
</ul>

// DATA
data () {
  return {
    menuItems: [
      { name: 'Split up', action: this.split('up') },
      { name: 'Split down', action: this.split('down') },
      { name: 'Split left', action: this.split('left') },
      { name: 'Split right', action: this.split('right') }
    ]
  }

  // METHODS
  methods: {
    split (direction) {
    store.actions.openWindow(direction)
    store.actions.closeMenu()
  }
}
```

But right now I get this error:

`[Vue warn]: v-on:click="menuItem.action" expects a function value, got undefined`

Meaning that I'm passing the value of `action` wrongly.

What's the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `vue.js`, but [from the documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/#v-on), the `click` binding expect a function.

Maybe you could try the following:

```
menuItems: [
    // split function and arguments
    { name: 'Split up', action: this.split, arg: 'up' }
    // ...
]
```

Then in your html:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="menuItem in menuItems">
    <a @click="menuItem.action(menuItem.arg)">{{ menuItem.name }}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or you could also try something like:

```
menuItems: [
    // create a new function
    { name: 'Split up', action: function() { return this.split('up') } }
    // ...
]
```

in your HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="menuItem in menuItems">
    <a @click="menuItem.action()">{{ menuItem.name }}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. The second example only works like this: `action: () => { return this.split('left') }`.